# Cannot convert ‘char (*)[1024]’ to ‘char*’ in return

Tags: c, readfile

I want read a simple file line by line and save the content into an array. If I compile the source code I get this error:

```
test.C: In function ‘char* read_file(int, int, const char*)’:
test.C:14:11: error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[1024]’ to ‘char*’ in return
    return words;
           ^
```

What does it means? Why can I not return a pointer of an 2D-Array? Here is the source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * read_file(int buf, int size, const char *fname){
   char words[size][buf];
   FILE *fptr = NULL; 
   int idx = 0;

   fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
   while(fgets(words[idx], buf, fptr)) {
      words[idx][strlen(words[idx]) - 1] = '\0';
      idx++;
   }
   return words;
}

int main(void) {
   char * words;
   words = read_file(1024, 100, "text.txt");
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
}
```

Comment: 'char words[size][buf];' - automatic storage, >GONE< after return.

Comment: You don't want to do what this appears to be trying regardless of that conversion error. The link in Lashane's comment is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually have *two* problems: The first one is about the error. An array of array of `char` is not the same as a pointer to `char`. As arrays decays to pointers, an array of arrays of `char` is equivalent to a pointer to array of `char`, or `char (*)[buf]` in your specific case.

The second problem is worse, and that is you try to return a pointer to a local variable. Local variables go out of scope once the function returns, and basically cease to exist. So once the function returns the pointer is no longer valid.

Since you use variable-length arrays, one solution you have is to allocate the arrays dynamically, as a pointer to pointer to `char`, i.e. `char **`, and return that. Another solution is to pass the array as an argument.

---

Simplest solution, in my opinion, declare the array in the `main` function and pass it to the function, that way you don't have to bother with pointers and dynamic allocation, and more specifically with freeing the memory later.

Something like this:

```
#define STRING_COUNT  100    // Number of strings
#define STRING_SIZE   1024   // Size of each string

// Open and read the file, returns the number of "words" read
size_t read_file(const char *filename, char (*words)[STRING_SIZE])
{
    // Implement the function...
    // Don't forget to return the number of "words", actually lines, you read
}

int main(void)
{
    char words[STRING_COUNT][STRING_SIZE];
    size_t number_words = read_file("test.txt", words);

    // Use the "words" here...
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, can you give me a short example, please?

Comment: @Sam Added simple (incomplete) sample, showing how to pass the array in as an argument.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.